# Could I change or configure default log file location of eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, logging, rcp

Could I change or configure default log file location of eclipse ?
the default location is .medadata and default name is .log

I want to make them configurable.

Any hints will be more than welcome!

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward way to change this

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Log File Location is: workspace_location/.metadata/.log

You can set the workspace in the eclipse.ini with -Dosgi.instance.area.default or -data, for example 
`-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/AppData/Roaming/WorkspaceDirectory` see [The Eclipse runtime options](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) for more details.

Btw, with -showLocation, you can display the workspace path of the current workspace in the window title bar of a running eclipse.

Comment: could i rename log file name from .log to <mylog>.log  ?

Comment: assuming your using org.eclipse.osgi.framework.log.FrameworkLog you can set the log path for your own plugin like this:  File workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation().toFile() and frwLog.setFile(new File(workspace, "yourname.log"), true) where frwLog is the osgi frameworkLog.

Comment: private static ILog log = Activator.getDefault().getLog(); it has no setFile method